# How to call from server to client with SignalR?

Tags: signalr

I'm following ["Broadcasting over a Hub from outside of a Hub"](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs), but my client browser isn't getting any messages. No errors either. It's like signalR doesn't know about my browser when it comes time to pull the hubContext and send messages.

However, my hub DOES act as expected when calling from client to hub.

My hub:

```
[HubName("myHub")]
public class MyHub : Hub
{        
    public void SaySomething(string message)
    {
        Clients.say(message);
    }

    public void SayHelloWorld()
    {
        Clients.say("hello world");
    }

}
```

Code from other place and time in server:

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
context.Clients.say(message);
```

And my client script:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.3.js" type="text/javascript" > </script>
<script src="signalr/hubs"> </script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
    var hub = $.connection.myHub;

    $.extend(hub, {
        Say: function(message) {
            alert(message); //this only works when the sayHelloWorld() method is executed
        }
    });

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function(){
            hub.sayHelloWorld(); //this works
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This code works fine for me. Which browser are you using and from where do you try to broadcast outside of the hub?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 22.0.1229.94 m on Windows. I've tried broadcasting from several different places in my code, from my UI layer (using Nancy), my domain service layer, and about everywhere I could think of.

Comment: @akoeplinger You say the code works for you. Mine works too, to a point. Can you also call the say method using the broadcast using the ConnectionManager? I just started over and re-built the solution according to the SignalR wiki and I get the same thing. I can communicate from the client to the server (which allows server to client in the same instance), but I cannot broadcast... no error, no message.

Comment: I am not able to figure where you are going wrong. Check SignalR stock ticker sample, it is available via NuGet. In the sample, all client calls are done using ConnectionManager. It might help you in resolving your issue.

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?

Comment: Latest from nuget today.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest nuget package (v 1.0.1) try:

```
$.extend(hub.client, {
        say: function(message) {
            alert(message); //this only works when the sayHelloWorld() method is executed
        }
```

And:

```
$.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function(){
            hub.server.sayHelloWorld(); //this works
        });
```

SignalR defined client and server properties for the hub, I was trying the MoveShape sample from a video and faced the same issue.

Hope it helps,